# Add Another Answer—Why?

Tags: discussion, answers

What exactly is the point of the <kbd>Add Another Answer</kbd> button? What would we need to do with it that we can't do by adding another clause to our already existing answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a really different approach to solve something, you can given another answer.

Why? Because our engine is designed to let the best answers float to the top. If you have two answers in one, it's unclear for others seeing the question which of the two solutions is the best.

So **if** you have a better solution than you previously had: answer it again

Comment: ... Quite a few times I give more than one (sometimes 3 or more) solutions in one answer - are you saying that I should write them all as separate answers? ... Would think that would be spamming :S

Comment: If you all value them equally, you can. But for instance when recommending an app, it's easier for the system to digest separate answers @Wil

Comment: That's cool - Makes perfect sense and for what you said in chat, +1

Comment: But does that happen much at all in practice?

Comment: I do it myself @digitxp and I'm sure others do it as well. Though I prefer giving just one kick-ass answer!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you see a question

> How do I do ***$thing*** using ***$app***.

First you answer the question.
A while later you think to yourself *Why is he using **$app** to do **$thing**, he should be using **$otherapp** instead.*

So you add another answer and let the other users decide witch is best.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is there to remind answerers that they already have answered that question. On questions with lots of answers, or questions with lots of answers that have been revived after a multi-month fallow period, it's not impossible to forget you've already answered a question. It happened to me once :}

Comment: I think he means: why is the button there in the first place? Why be able to post another answer?